# trouble seting up and useing mysql server remotely

Tags: mysql, node.js, linux, remote-access, vps

I am kinda new to dev and i wanted to host a mysql server on a vps to work with.

So i've setup my apache mysql and all i needed on my vps. Everything is working in local and i can access it with the ip on my browser.

But when i try to access the mysql server from my computer its never working...

in the terminal when i try to log in with `$ mysql -h 82.165.117.19 -u kataiga -p` i got the following error :

"ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '82.165.117.19' (113)"

And when i try to access the db with a node app(runing local on my pc) with the following code

```
import mysql from 'mysql';
console.log('Get connection ...');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "82.165.117.19",
    user: "kataiga",
    password: "psw",
    database : "node_chat"
  });
 
   con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connecté à la base de données MySQL!");
    con.query("SELECT eleves.id as 'eleve_id', eleves.nom as 'eleve_nom', eleves.cours_id, cours.nom as 'cours_nom', cours.date as 'cours_date' FROM eleves JOIN cours on eleves.cours_id = cours.id", function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
      });
  });
```

i got this error

```
Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 82.165.117.19:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/kataiga/project/chat_node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/kataiga/project/chat_node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/home/kataiga/project/chat_node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at file:///home/kataiga/project/chat_node/config/mysql.js:13:8
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5) {
  errno: -113,
  code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '82.165.117.19',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

i have already tried to remove the bind-adress and set it to 0.0.0.0 in the mysql config file both of those did not worked, the user i am trying to connect with on mysql have all privileges and his host name is %

my vps firewall is open on port 22, 80, 443, 3306 in TCP protocol with all ip allowed, the version runing is ubuntu 20.04

i hope this is clear enought i just don't know what to try/search for.

edit my mysqld.cnf look like this

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
 user           = mysql
 pid-file       = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 port           = 3306
 datadir        = /var/lib/mysql
#bind-address   = 82.165.117.119
#skip-networking
#skip-bind-address
# If MySQL is running as a replication slave, this should be
# changed. Ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmpdir
 tmpdir         = /tmp
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size         = 16M
# max_allowed_packet    = 64M
# thread_stack          = 256K

# thread_cache_size       = -1

# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP

# max_connections        = 151

# table_open_cache       = 4000

# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
#
# Log all queries
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/query.log
# general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
# slow_query_log                = 1
# slow_query_log_file   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
# long_query_time = 2
# log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
# server-id             = 1
# log_bin                       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
# binlog_expire_logs_seconds    = 2592000
max_binlog_size   = 100M
# binlog_do_db          = include_database_name
# binlog_ignore_db      = include_database_name
```

Comment: And what are the ports your VPS provider permits?

Comment: I can add any port i want

Comment: And what does your `my.cnf` look like?  Do you actually allow the server to bind to that IP, `sudo netstat -anp | grep 3306`?

Comment: the terminal return this

`tcp        0      0 82.165.117.19:3306      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31579/mysqld 
       
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      31579/mysqld`

Comment: i added the .cnf in the post

Comment: Can you also add the output of `sudo ufw status numbered`?  If you didn't make the IP address above up you only have 22, 53, and 80 open ...

Comment: `To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] Apache Full                ALLOW IN    Anywhere  
[ 2] 3306/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere  
[ 3] Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)  
[ 4] 3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)`

Comment: I'm somewhat baffled ... when you say `in the terminal when i try to log in with $ mysql -h 82.165.117.19 -u kataiga -p` ... are you running that on the VPS machine or locally? If locally - does it work if you ssh into the VPS and try it there?

Comment: if i log ssh into the vps it work yeah, but if i try without ssh its give me the error ine the post

Comment: So it's either your firewall locally, or the VPS supplier is blocking ports after all ... see my comment above about which ports show as open.